# RegEx to match a full string of various characters?

Tags: xml, regex, pattern-matching

I know this question has been asked at least 100 different times in at least 100 different ways but I'm really struggling to puzzle together everything I have found on this to create what i need.

I need a RegEx that can be used inside an XML Pattern restriction tag that matches these characters -

```
%&()"''*+,-./:;<=>?_#~@!$^[]{}0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

As one full string, not sigle words or characters. It can include spaces, but NOT tab spaces or return key characters.

This is what I have so far - `[A-Za-z0-9$-/:-?@#{-~!^_\'\[\]  *]`

Thanks in advance,

Ash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[..]` is a character set, and will match any single character given it is in the set. If you want to match a while string, then you need repetition `*` will match **zero or more** and `+` will match **one or more**. Since you want to match the entire string you also need to anchor your expression, you can do this with `^` for start of string and `$` for end of string.

So the following regex will match `star of string` `one or more characters from the given set` `end of string`:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9$-/:-?@#{-~!^_\'\[\] *]+$
```

If you are interested in learning about regex you might want to read up on the basics there are lots of sites with tons of information, such as [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much for the answer and most of all thank you for explaining the workings of it to me.